# Mysql return result if no result in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, null, return

Let's say I has this sql line:

```
SELECT (something) 
FROM user_data, user_profile_image 
WHERE user_data.user_id='6' (AND user_profile_image.user_id='6')
```

How do I make sure that it returns informations from the user_data field if there is no containing data in user_profile_image related to that user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT u.*,i.user_profile_image FROM user_data u LEFT JOIN `USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_TABLE` i ON i.user_id=u.user_id WHERE u.user_id='6'
```

I am unsure what your USER_PROFILE_IMAGE_TABLE is so you will need to change that.

Comment: Hmm... It seems like i does not work. This is the code in completeness:

SELECT (something)
FROM
 `users`
LEFT JOIN `profile_images`
 ON `users`.`user_id`=`profile_images`.`user_id`
WHERE
 `profile_images`.`user_id` = '". $uid ."'
AND
 `users`.`user_id` = '". $uid ."'
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT something
FROM user_data
LEFT JOIN user_profile_image
ON user_profile_image.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE user_data.user_id = '6'
AND user_profile_image.user_id IS NULL;
```

You want to `LEFT JOIN` the detail page on the foreign key field being equal to the primary key field of the first table, and select the rows from the first table such that there IS no matching row from the second table.

In the query you gave, there's no join criteria, so it would be a Cartesian product - every row of `user_data` merged with every single row of `user_profile_image`.

Comment: If i set IS null to = '6' (user id 6 has no profile images) Then Sql returns nothing. If i use user_id 4 (a user with an image) sql returns rows :/

Comment: What is the foreign key field? What key is used to match `user_profile_image` to `user_data`?

Comment: There is no foreign key at the moment, is that necessary for this?

Comment: How do you know which `user_profile_image` belongs to which `user_data`? I don't mean a foreign key constraint, but what is the value that exists in both tables to equate them? Either `user_data.user_id` also appears in `user_profile_image`, or `user_profile_image` has a key field (such as `user_profile_image_id`) which also appears in `user_data`. Can you put your schema and query on sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, IFNULL(up.user_id, 'No Data In user_profile_image') UserId, 
       IFNULL(up.user_image_id, 'No Data In user_profile_image') user_image_id
FROM user_data u 
LEFT JOIN user_profile_image up ON u.user_id = up.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id = 6;
```

Check this link [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67e21/1)